# Atom Snippets not working for Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, atom-editor, code-snippets

I am trying to make a snippet for the headings of a Shell Script,

`#!/bin/bash`

`Name of program`

`Author`

And that kind of stuff. But my snippet is not working!
Here's my Snippet:

```
"'.text.sh':
  'Headings':
    'prefix': 'head'
    'body': '#!/bin/bash

    # Author:

    # Name:

    # Date of Completion (Update)
    # Date of LEGACY'"
```

(Sorry it wouldn't exactly how it looks with the spaces, etc. But I edited it so its as close as possible.)

Comment: Are the double quotes at the start and end actually there in the file?

Comment: Yes, When I tabbed "Snip" it replaces "Snip" with 

``"'.source.js':

  'Snippet Name':

    'prefix': 'Snippet Trigger'

    'body': 'Hello World!'"``

Comment: BTW, as an aside, *bash* scripts shouldn't generally have `.sh` extensions. Executable commands don't typically have extensions *at all* on UNIX -- you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`, and while a Python module may be named `foo.py`, the executable wrapper installed for it by setuptools is just named `foo`. And if something is a bash *library* as opposed to a bash *script*, its extension should be `.bash` so folks know not to try to source it into scripts run with `/bin/sh` or another non-bash interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper definition is:

```
'.source.shell':
  'Headings':
    'prefix': 'head'
    'body': """
      #!/bin/bash

      # Author:

      # Name:

      # Date of Completion (Update)
      # Date of LEGACY'
    """
```

The `.source.shell` definition can be found by using the `Editor: Log Cursor Scope` command while having a shell script open.

Note that the body *contains* a multi-line string; it isn't *inside* a multi-line string itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helped! It also seems the " 's were leftovers from tabbing "Snip"